# Concatenate index of a list into a string variables

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I have a list

```
list = ['1a-b2', '2j-u3', '5k-hy', '1h-j3']
```

and I have a  string like below

```
main = '{"datatype: null" "country_code":"eu","offset":0,"id":"2y-9k"}'
```

How can I replace the `id` value in string, with its respective index in the master list ?

For Eg.,
I want to replace the "1h-j3" in the `main` string with its index in `list`. This to be done in a loop for all as well.

I have tried to concatenate using +, % but they did not work, kindly help me with this. Both the list indexes and main variable are of data type string

expected output is as follows
in first loop

```
main = '{"datatype: null" "country_code":"eu","offset":0,"id":"1a-b2"}'
```

in second loop

```
main = '{"datatype: null" "country_code":"eu","offset":0,"id":"2j-u3"}'
```

in third loop

```
main = '{"datatype: null" "country_code":"eu","offset":0,"id":"5k-hy"}'
```

and so on

Comment: I tried reading your question 3 times and I still don't understand what you are trying to do. What is `1hj3` mean? What do you mean by *adding each index in a loop*? Also, what code have you written so far? Where is it going wrong?

Comment: Is the `main` going to be a valid JSON ?

Comment: it is a category id and main is kind of parameters of url, i just want to use my category id in place of this "1h-j3"

Comment: i just want to know if i can use my indexes in this string or not, if yes then how because i have tried couple of concatenating techniques but they dont work

Comment: @MalikZaib 1h-j3 is not a part of the list that you provided. If you are saying that the value of `id` is guaranteed to be in the list and that you just want to use the index of the value of `id` from the list, then please re-word your question. And I think @Kris has the answer for you below.

Comment: no it is not guaranteed to be in the list im not trying to look for the value of id in list but instead im trying to get the values of my list replace the value of id in main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can think of 2 approaches, based on the type of data you have for the `main` variable. See below.

In case, the value is a proper JSON

```
import json

items_list = ['1a-b2', '2j-u3', '5k-hy', "1h-j3"]
# if main_dict was a valid json
main_dict = json.loads('{"datatype": "null", "country_code":"eu","offset":0,"id":"1h-j3"}')
main_dict["id"] = items_list.index(main_dict["id"])
main_dict = json.dumps(main_dict)
```

Other case, its a dirty string manipulation. May be there are better ways,

```
# If its not a valid JSON
str_main = '{"datatype: null" "country_code":"eu","offset":0,"id":"1h-j3"}'
import re

# Use a regex to find the key for replacement.
found = re.findall(r'"id":".*"', str_main, re.IGNORECASE)
if found and len(found) > 0:
    key = found[0].split(":")[1].replace('"', '')
    _id = items_list.index(key)
    str_main = str_main.replace(key, str(_id))

print(str_main)
```

produced output

```
{"datatype: null" "country_code":"eu","offset":0,"id":"3"}
```

## --UPDATE--

As per your requirement updated in question, then it will be a simple loop I assume like below.

```
items_list = ['1a-b2', '2j-u3', '5k-hy', "1h-j3"]
base_str = '{"datatype: null" "country_code":"eu","offset":0,"id":"_ID_"}'
for item in items_list:
     main = base_str.replace('_ID_', item)
     print(main)
```

Produces output like

```
{"datatype: null" "country_code":"eu","offset":0,"id":"1a-b2"}
{"datatype: null" "country_code":"eu","offset":0,"id":"2j-u3"}
{"datatype: null" "country_code":"eu","offset":0,"id":"5k-hy"}
{"datatype: null" "country_code":"eu","offset":0,"id":"1h-j3"}
```

Comment: thanks @kris but can i get the index value instead of "3" in the output

Comment: Well, you can post the input, an expected output etc in the question itself. This is what I could understand. This code works fine in that context :-)

Comment: i have updated the  question with expected output can u take a look one more time, thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer, I suppose this is what you need. !

Comment: thank you @kris it worked like a charm, was stuck on it for couple of days, once again thanks for the help, really apricate it